# NFS Shares - one IP Read/Write, rest Read-Only

Tags: networking, server, mount, nfs, nas

I'm trying to create some NFS shares for my home network so that I can manage my NAS more easily. I'm currently using Samba for the household, but NFS is faster for me since I use Ubuntu (everyone else, except the NAS, are running Windows).

What I want to do is create some NFS shares that are Read Only for everyone except my machine. I have the NFS shares working ok, as in I can mount them on my computer and browse the folders, but I'm forced to be read-only on them, which is frustrating since I've declared in my config/export that my machines be read/write.

My /etc/exports file looks like this (for example of one line - there are sevral like this with the same result):

```
/mnt/TVShows    matt-pc.*(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check) 192.168.1.0/25(ro,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

matt-pc.1 and matt-pc.2 are both defined in the NAS's hosts file. But regardless of that, hard coding the IPs doesn't work, either.

This doesn't work either:

```
/mnt/TVShows    matt-pc.*(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check) *(ro,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

I can still only read-only mount.

The drives are mounted as Read/Write on the NAS, and my Samba shares settings work fine (I can force login as my user account on the NAS, and be able to read and write files).

If I format the shares like this:

```
/mnt/TVShows    matt-pc.*(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

I just get permissions errors when trying to mount on the client machine (my machine).

This is how I'm mounting on my client machine:

```
nas.local:/mnt/TVShows  /mnt/NFS/TVShows nfs auto,noatime,nolock,bg,nfsvers=4,intr,tcp,actimeo=1800 0 0
```

Can I work this?

Comment: What do you get from `getent hosts matt-pc` from your NAS?  And why do you add a `.*` after?  The important is what your machine resolves the names too.  And there is `getent`(1) good tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To export `/mnt/TVShows` as `rw` from `nas` to `matt-pc` and `ro` to all other you could write this in `/etc/exports:

```
#
/mnt/TVShows matt-pc(rw,no_subtree_check) 192.168.1.0/24(ro)
```

Notice that the order is important. The first machine name/IP/network that maches is used when exporting to one machine, so have most specific machine first and most general last. Do not end with a catch all that gives to much rights.

Also remember that each set of options is inherent to next, so you only need to be specific on first. The rest is only changes from previous settings. Also avoid set opinions you don't need. (And always read relevant `man`(1) pages and documentation in `/usr/share/doc/"package name"/`)

Also check how the names you are using are resolved properly. To use that, use the `getent`(1) command.  Like this:

```
$ getent hosts matt-pc
```

And how that works depend on the `resolv.conf` and `/etc/hosts`  (or actually the contents of `/etc/nsswitch.conf`).

To mount you do like this from each machine:

```
/etc/fstab
# ro, that is this line in all but matt-pc
nas.local:/mnt/TVShows  /mnt/NFS/TVShows nfs auto,ro,noatime,nolock,bg,nfsvers=4,intr,tcp 0 0
# rw, that is this line in only matt-pc
nas:/mnt/TVShows  /mnt/NFS/TVShows nfs auto,rw,noatime,nfsvers=4,tcp 0 0
```

Notice though that don't use more arguments than you really need.

(Yes, I prefer to have disks on servers mounted under `/srv/`, as that is for server resources, and `/mnt/` is more for temporary mountings.  I usually have `/srv/web/`, `/srv/files/music/`, `/srv/files/video` etc.  It maskes it easier to make backups)

Comment: wow Thanks @Anders !  ....q:   from where is the quote "each set of options is inherent to next, so you only need to be specific on first. The rest is only changes from previous settings." ?? This is critical information I overlooked in any man page I read. Where can I find that?

Comment: I got it from the man pages, as usual. And some testing and watching log files with tail(1). :-)
And yes, space ARE important, don't use extra spaces.